# Novice trying to learn java, html, curl or whatever toward learning how to automate an interaction with an online dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, curl

BACKGROUND INFO:

I am a retired duffer with moderate experience developing windows applications for PC.   I am trying to learn java, html, curl or whatever toward learning how to automate an interaction with an online dictionary.  My purpose in doing so is to support some word puzzle games I am developing.

My system is a HP laptop running 64-bit Windows Professional.   I develop my apps using MS visual studio 2015 Express.

Needless to say, I have no idea what I am doing vis-à-vis curl.  Yes, I have read all of the online documentation and tutorials on html, java and curl I could find, but I very quickly find said info over my head.

So please forgive me if this posting is vague or insufficiently specific.  I’m doing the best I can.

I feel like I might be on the right track but do not know how to capture the response from the online server.  Can someone steer me toward achieving my goal stated above?  Thank you for attending to this.

Robert Hoech

ISSUE STATEMENT:

CMD:

```
C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Rob\CURL>curl -v http://www.merriam-webster/dictionary
/capricious >data.txt
```

WRITTEN TO data.txt

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

WRITTEN TO CONSOLE:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*
  Trying 198.105.254.23:80...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0*
connect to 198.105.254.23 port 80 failed: Timed out
*   Trying 198.105.244.23:80...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0*
Connected to www.merriam-webster (198.105.244.23) port 80 (#0)
> GET /dictionary/capricious HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.merriam-webster
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 20:48:42 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: close
< Location: http://localhost
< Expires: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 20:48:41 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
<
{ [189 bytes data]
100   178    0   178    0     0      8      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--    43
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: If there’s a redirect it needs to be followed. That said there’s no guarantee the data returned is static, eg, if the site loads data via Ajax then curry won’t help. The first step would be to look at the network traffic generated in a browser in the network tab and take it from there. That said, there is likely a TOS you’d need to keep in mind. It might be better to get a local, static file with the data you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting via "curl" is a 301 Redirect to "http://localhost".  That means read the file off "your machine".  Obviously, that won't work ...

I think that this is the Merriam-Webster site telling you that what you are trying to do is not permitted by their [Terms of Service](https://www.merriam-webster.com/terms-of-use).

If you wanted to ignore that (and risk a possible lawsuit!) you could try changing the agent string to trick the website into thinking your application is a web browser.

A better idea would be:

- Contact Merriam-Webster to see if there is an API service (or something) that you are permit you to use.  (You may have to pay for it.)
- Trying and find an alternative *free* online dictionary.  (Make sure that you read the Terms of Service thoroughly!)
- Find a free fixed word list and embed it in your application.

---

**UPDATE** - So I tried this myself, and here is what I found:

1. The URL you are using is incorrect:

   ```
   http://www.merriam-webster/dictionary/capricious
   ```

   The hostname part is incorrect.  It should be "www.merriam-webster.com".
2. If you use "http:" with the correct hostname, it redirects to "https:"
3. Curling

   ```
   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capricious
   ```

   gives an HTML document which looks like it has the definition in it.  Whether it is scrape-able in practice ... I can't say.  (But I couldn't get the page to pay attention to an "Accept: text/plain" header.)

But I also found that there is an official Merriam-Webster API; see https://dictionaryapi.com/.  The page says that there is a free / non-commercial use option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solutions.  My apps already use solution #3, and I was hoping to upgrade to use either of the first 2 solutions.   Merriam-Webster offers a free (with limitations) JSON script which appears to be what I am seeking, if I can figure out how to make it work.